# What is the dropout/switch major rate for engineering bachelor?

Tags: united-states, engineering, bachelor

What is the average dropout and switch major rate for US 4 year engineering college for students entering bachelor's degree program after 2010?

It is pretty hard for me to find any good reference.

Comment: 4-year schools only? Success rates for community college students are extremely low.

Comment: I assume you have read the document [STEM Attrition: College Students’ Paths Into and Out of STEM Fields November, 2013](http://nces.ed.gov/pubs2014/2014001rev.pdf) where it says: A total of **48** percent of bachelor’s degree students and **69** percent of associate’s degree students who entered STEM fields between 2003 and **2009** had left these fields by spring 2009.