# The drop/switch major rate for people "intended" major in engineering in US?

Tags: united-states, undergraduate

The drop/switch major rate of engineering bachlors programs for people "intended" major in engineering except software engineering in US?

Please notice that the attrition rate from most source are for student who already declare major typically in their junior year/very end of their sophmore year, but what is the average drop/switch major rate in the US for the "intended" freshman student who go to college of engineering? In another word, what is the rate of these intended engineers did not get a eningineering bachlors?

Related question: [What is the dropout/switch major rate for engineering bachelor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/67868/what-is-the-dropout-switch-major-rate-for-engineering-bachelor)

Comment: It's quite high at my place (upwards of 50% because many students enter without enough math background and never get up to speed), but I've no idea where you would find comprehensive data.

Comment: There was an article in the Sunday LA Times (Aug 7 2016) that touched on this, but related to minority retention in STEM from 2004 and didn't break the numbers down to individual fields. At best, the rate for "finished in under 5 years with same degree" was under 50%, and for blacks and Hispanics it was under 25%.